# Upstart log stdout and stderr to file not working as expected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart

When in bash I can run:

```
java -jar server.jar &>> log.txt
```

And it combines the stdout and stderr into `log.txt`.  However when I have this line in my [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com) `.conf` file, it does not do this:

```
exec java -jar server.jar &>> log.txt
```

I’ve also tried separating the logs as:

```
exec java -jar server.jar >> log.txt 2>> err.txt
```

And this doesn’t work either. It *will* work if I make it overwrite instead of append, e.g.

```
exec java -jar server.jar > log.txt 2> err.txt
```

But this is not acceptable. Is this a bug in Upstart or is there something I’m misunderstanding? I’m running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, Upstart version 1.12.1, and I’m fairly new to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create the file yourself. Let upstart manage this so it will log both stdout and stderr to `/var/log/upstart/<service>.log` :

```
console log
exec java -jar server.jar
```

If you need to change the directory path you can use `--logdir <directory>`.